# Why do skin calluses not heal sometimes and remain tough until they fall off?

Tags: dermatology, exercise, hand, calluses

Bar exercises such as pull-ups, toes-to-bar etc. usually cause skin calluses on one's hand, just below the place where the fingers are connected to the hand, e.g.:[image: picture].

So the skin in these areas hardens, but if you let it rest for a few days, these calluses disappear and the skin returns (more or less) to its original softness and flexibility.

However, I've noticed that if the tough skin is torn in such a way that it becomes sort of "skin flap" (i.e. attached to the palm only on one side of the callus), then it remains hard and does not revert to its original softness, until it falls off. **Why is that? What makes a flap of skin to toughen irreversibly?**

Comment: I would imagine it is due to the fact that the skin is broken and there is less surface area able to re-oil.